# Passing a variable through form action using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, coldfusion, action

How do I send a variable through jquery attached to the multiple form actions? I need to be able to send across a #clientId# with the form action but I am setting the form action in jquery depending on what drop down choice the user selects. For example:
    if($('#uTransaction').val() == 1){
                  $('#toolActions').attr('action','networkTools-transfer.cfm?otherID=#clientId#); <-- this does not work
              }

Here is my code:

```
HTML
 <form id="toolActions" name="toolActions" method="post" action="">
    <div id="action-div">
        <table class="action-table">
                <tr class="action-row">
                        <td>Selected Tools Action:
                            <select name="uTransaction" id="uTransaction" >
                                <option value="">--Select One--</option>
                                <cfloop query="networkTool_Actions">
                                    <cfoutput><option  value="#networkTool_Actions.Tool_Actions_ID#">#networkTool_Actions.Tool_Actions_DESC#</option></cfoutput>
                                </cfloop>
                            </select>
  </div>
</form>

jQuery

$('#toolActions').submit(function() {

          if($('#uTransaction').val() == 1){
              $('#toolActions').attr('action','networkTools-transfer.cfm');
          }
          if($('#uTransaction').val() == 2){
              $('#toolActions').attr('action','networkTools-accept.cfm');
          }
          if($('#uTransaction').val() == 3){
              $('#toolActions').attr('action','networkTools-retire.cfm');
          }
          if($('#uTransaction').val() == 4){
              $('#toolActions').attr('action','networkTools-recover.cfm');
          }
          if($('#uTransaction').val() == 5){
              $('#toolActions').attr('action','networkTools-repair.cfm');
          }
      });
```

Comment: Is your JS within a CF file or is the JS separate?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
$('input').on('some event',function(){
    $('form').get(0).setAttribute('action', 'create_new_url');
}
```

I guess it would be something like 'select' on 'blur' / 'change' maybe?

Here's a jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/95gff/

When you change the select input, check the action on the form via firebug or your preferred debugger
and you'll see action does indeed change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script> 
    $('#uTransaction').change(function() { //when you will select any option in dropdown

    var val=$('#uTransaction').val();//get value of that option 
              if(val == 1){  

              window.location.href='networkTools-transfer.cfm?otherID='+val;
              }
              if(val == 2){
               window.location.href='networkTools-accept.cfm?otherID='+val;
              } 
              if(val == 3){
            window.location.href='networkTools-retire.cfm?otherID='+val;
              }
              if(val == 4){
                window.location.href='networkTools-recover.cfm?otherID='+val;
              }
              if(val == 5){ 
                window.location.href='networkTools-repair.cfm?otherID='+val;
              }
          });
  </script> 



 if user wants form to submit ,then try this

 <script> 
     $('#uTransaction').change(function() { //when you will select any option in dropdown

        var val=$('#uTransaction').val();//get value of that option 
                  if(val == 1){  

                $('#toolActions').attr('action','networkTools-transfer.cfm?otherID='+val);
                  } 
                  if(val == 2){
                 $('#toolActions').attr('action','networkTools-accept.cfm?otherID='+val);
                  } 

              }); 
 </script> 
    and add this in html:

    <input type="submit" name="" value="submit"/>
```

Comment: Does this solution not make the form useless? As no post will happen?

Comment: yes,there is no need of form if we use  above script.

Comment: Oh I see, it only exists to redirect.

Comment: i have updated my answer,if he wants to submit form....we have to add submit button in html.

Comment: he did 2 mistakes... he used .submit instead .change ...he didn't get value of select......and he didn't added submit button....he only added actions to form.

Comment: I ended up with this as a solution.
    if(val == 1){
      $('#toolActions').attr('action','networkTools-transfer.cfm?otherAttuid=<cfoutput>#client.id#</cfoutput>');
     }
   if(val == 2){
      $('#toolActions').attr('action','networkTools-accept.cfm?otherAttuid=<cfoutput>#client.id#</cfoutput>');
     }
I added this to the coldfusion page because it would only work in a cfm page and not in a js page.